# GCC - enable cross compilation when target is the same as host

Tags: linux, gcc, x86-64

Say I wanted to build a cross compiler for a platform with the spec:

- x86_64-linux-gnu
- kernel version != host's kernel
- glibc version != host's glibc

I then configure GCC on my PC which is also `x86_64-linux-gnu`.

This leads to a situation where the `build`, `host` and `target` parameters are all the same which is considered a `native` build.

What is the correct thing to do in this situation to make GCC cross build?

I ask because I am having issues with one of the bootstrap stages which then seems to work if I specify the `target` as `x86_86-<vendor>-linux-gnu`.